# How to use window.onbeforeunload in React for showing popup for reload if the user clicks on reload

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to use window.onbeforeunload in React for showing popup for reload if the user clicks on reload.

I tried doing this it is not working

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleRefresh);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleRefresh);
  };
});
```

Comment: If you are using `react-router-dom` - then do it this way.
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/preventing-transitions

Answer (score -1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload(handleRefresh)
    return () => {
      window.onbeforeunload("null")
    };
  }, []);
```